# How to assign CMD output to a variable and print in CMD windows

Tags: windows

i am running below command in CMD, i want to assign the output from the below command to a variable and print it in CMD

wmic cpu get name,numberofcores,numberoflogicalprocessors

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to redirect the output to a text file and then process it to store into a variable:

**myscript.bat:**

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
wmic cpu get name,numberofcores,numberoflogicalprocessors > out.txt
set txt=
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (out.txt) do set txt=!txt!%%i
echo !txt!
Endlocal
```